# Casting substrings with linq into a list of object and than sorting it base on property in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

This have to be in vb.net linq, i'm pretty sure I could do it in c#, but I cant find any good enough translator to help me ... even the answers I find here in SO seems to only be written in linq, hence the question which might be a duplicate of a c# one.

That being said, considering these 2 classes :

```
Public class User
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Teams As TeamList

      Public sub New(d as string, results as TeamList)
            me.name = d
            me.Teams = results
      end sub
end class

Public Class TeamList
    Public Property TeamName() As String
    Public Property fullscore() As list(of object) 

    Public sub New(name as string, value as list(of string))
        me.TeamName = name
        me.fullscore = value
        me.fullscore = getFullScore(value) (return a list of object)
    end sub
End Class
```

I'm struggling in the final steps of my linq -to - object : (you can copy /paste this in linqpad)

```
Sub Main

 dim Definition as new Dictionary(of String, object) 

definition.add("user1_redTeam-02", new object)
definition.add("user1_redTeam-01", new object)
definition.add("user1_blueTeam-03", new object)
definition.add("user2_redTeam-01", new object)
definition.add("user1_redTeam-03", new object)
definition.add("user1_blueTeam-01",new object)
definition.add("user2_blueTeam-01", new object)
definition.add("user1_blueTeam-02", new object)
definition.add("user2_redTeam-02", new object)

Dim q3  = (From userlists In Definition.Keys.GroupBy(Function(s) s.Split("_")(0)) _
        Select New With _
        {.UserName = userlists.Key, _
         .animationList = (From scList In userlists.GroupBy(Of String)(Function(s) s.Split("-")(0)) _
        Select New With {.Team = scList.Key, _
                          .Score = scList.ToList()})})
  q3.dump()
End Sub
```

this is the result : 
[image: Linq results]

now, all I want is to sort the .score attribute (just a simple .sort(), and instead of returning an anonymous q3 object, which I,m cluless to transform, I'd like the q3 to be a list(of User)

it think it should looks like this ... but I cant make it works, i always gets some linq conversion errors :
 Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,System.String],UserQuery+User]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserQuery+User]'.

```
Dim q3 as List(of User)= (From userlists In Definition.Keys.GroupBy(Function(s) s.Split("_")(0)) _
Select New User(userlists.Key, (From scList In userlists.GroupBy(Of String)(Function(s) s.Split("-")(0)) _
Select New TeamList(scList.Key, scList.ToList()))))
```

Comment: I must go get my kid from kindergarden, I'll br back in 30 minutes, sorry If I miss any question

Comment: geez, dude how much more data you want me to include ... theres everything I'm working with in there ... I want exactly what I have here as the result, but not in an anonymous q3 object. I want q3 to be a list (of whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code examples seem to be incorrect - for example, it seems like `User.Teams` should be a list of some type, not a `TeamList` object, which isn't really a list.  Anyway, with a little modification, this is what I came up with - maybe it's close to what you were looking for (a list of users with the scores sorted).  You can paste into LINQPad to run it.

```
Sub Main
    Dim Definition As New Dictionary(of String, Object) 
    definition.add("user1_redTeam-02", New Object)
    definition.add("user1_redTeam-01", New Object)
    definition.add("user1_blueTeam-03", New Object)
    definition.add("user2_redTeam-01", New Object)
    definition.add("user1_redTeam-03", New Object)
    definition.add("user1_blueTeam-01",New Object)
    definition.add("user2_blueTeam-01", New Object)
    definition.add("user1_blueTeam-02", New Object)
    definition.add("user2_redTeam-02", New Object)
    Dim q3 = (
        From userlists In Definition.Keys.GroupBy(Function(s) s.Split("_"c)(0))
        Select New User(
            userlists.Key,
            (From scList In userlists.GroupBy(Function(s) s.Split("-"c)(0))
            Select New Team(scList.Key.Split("_"c)(1), scList.OrderBy(Function(s) s).ToList())).ToList()
        )
    ).ToList()
    q3.dump()
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
Public class User
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Teams() As List(Of Team)
    Public Sub New(d As String, results As List(Of Team))
        Me.Name = d
        Me.Teams = results
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Team
    Public Property TeamName() As String
    Public Property FullScore() As List(Of String) 
    Public Sub New(name As String, value As List(Of String))
        Me.TeamName = name
        Me.FullScore = value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Wow, ok I just reread it, and of course you are right ... I needed a full night sleep on that one.